# How to pass subclass in function with base class typehint

Tags: python, inheritance

I have a base class `A` from what I inherit in sub class `B`.
I have a function where an argument has this base class `A` as typehint.
Now I want to pass to this function sub class `B`.
This works, but I get a warning in my IDE "Expected type A, got B instead".

How to do that correctly?

```
class A: pass

class B(A): pass

def test(a: A): pass

test(B()) # <- expected type A, got B instead
```

**EDIT:**

I found the issue.
I accidentally used the wrong base class as typehint in the `test(a: WRONG)`.

The code above works!

Thanks all for your answers!

Comment: what IDE are you using?

Comment: @DeepSpace Thanks for your response. I'm also using PyCharm 2020.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hinting `a: A` means that `a` is an **instance** of `A` (or of its subclasses).

`test(B)` passes the **class** `B` to test, not an **instance**.

If you pass an instance `test(B())` the warning goes away.

If you actually meant for `test` to accept the class itself, you have to use a tad more advanced hinting:

```
from typing import Type

class A:
    pass

class B(A):
    pass

def test(a: Type[A]): pass  # <- no warning here

test(B)
```

Comment: beat me to the `Type[A]` answer!  :)